# clone text and insert into closet caption span

Tags: jquery

I have a page with several tables , all have different text in the th , and i wanted to clone the th text and place it in the captions.

I tried this , but it pulls every th text and puts into every caption

```
$( 'caption span' ).each(function( index ) {
  $(this).text($('th').text());
});
```

Sample of HTML

```
<table class="report"><caption><span>Place New Text Here For This Tables th</span></caption><tbody><tr><th>Clone This Text #1</th></tr>
</tbody></table>

<table class="report"><caption><span>Place New Text Here For This Tables th</span></caption><tbody><tr><th>Clone This Text #2</th></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Navigate up to the container table with `closest()`
2. Use `find()` to get that tables `th`

```js
$('caption span').each(function(index) {
  $(this).text($(this).closest('table').find('th').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="report">
  <caption><span>Place New Text Here For This Tables th</span>
  </caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Clone This Text #1</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="report">
  <caption><span>Place New Text Here For This Tables th</span>
  </caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Clone This Text #2</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ty , thats what i needed, will mark as answer once time allows me to do so